# Deserialize iTunes rss xml

Tags: c#, serialization

I am struggling with the xml schema put forth by iTunes. I’m able to deserialize the elements like title and link etc. But not those prefixed with itunes: such as itunes:image and     itunes:duration

`[XmlElementAttribute("itunes:duration")]` does not work. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were looking for:

```
[XmlElementAttribute(AttributeName = "duration", Namespace = "itunes")]
```